# Why does the __mul__ magic method behave differently than the human-readable version?

Tags: python

I've been explaining Python magic functions to someone and I naturally showed these examples:

```
In [1]: str("v").__mul__(5)
Out[1]: 'vvvvv'

In [2]: "v" * 5
Out[2]: 'vvvvv'
```

But then I moved on to how transitivity is implemented and tried also this example that failed:

```
In [3]: 5 * "v"
Out[3]: 'vvvvv'

In [4]: int(5).__mul__("v")
Out[4]: NotImplemented
```

I was not able to explain why this last one did not work. Could you help me?

Comment: Minor side-note: There's no benefit to calling `int` on `5` (what with it already being an `int`). While you can't just put the method call `.` immediately after a `5`, plain parens are enough to avoid the ambiguity with `float` literals: `(5).__mul__("v")`. Even a single space is enough, though it's a little less obvious what you're doing with `5 .__mul__("v")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `__mul__` only handles the case where the operator is on the *left* side of the operator. `int.__mul__` doesn't handle `str`, only `str.__mul__` handles `int`. The actual `*` operator for `5 * 'v'` first asks `int.__mul__` if it knows how to handle a `str`, and when it returns `NotImplemented`, it asks `str.__rmul__` (note the `r`, for "reflected") if it knows how to handle being on the right hand side of the operator when `int` is on the left; it does, so you get the expected result.

Some overly language lawyer quotes from [the Python Data Model section on the forward and reverse binary operator overloading special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__):

> [`__r*__`] functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation, and the operands are of different types. For instance, to evaluate the expression `x - y`, where `y` is an instance of a class that has an `__rsub__()` method, `type(y).__rsub__(y, x)` is called if `type(x).__sub__(x, y)` returns `NotImplemented`.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` binary operator doesn't just call `__mul__`. Specifically, `a * b` does the following:

- First, it calls `a.__mul__(b)`. If that function returns anything *other* than `NotImplemented` or if it raises an exception, we take that value or exception.
- If the first call returned the special built-in constant `NotImplemented`, we call `b.__rmul__(a)` (note that the arguments are reversed).

So if you call `"v".__rmul__(5)`, you'll get the result you want.

If your goal is to have a function that behaves identically to the star operator, you can do it with a lambda (`lambda x, y: x * y`), or you can import [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul)